# Exiting Flask server raises "OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor" when app.run(debug=True)

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, debugging, flask

Is this just part of the debugging process with Flask? Is this because the Flask server is reading into a file that it is writing to? Am I not closing connections properly?

From [what I can gather](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20554093/system-errno-9.html) errno(9) indicates:

> (bad file number), when the file descriptor you are using is not valid. Either the file descriptor refers to no open file, or a read (or write) request is made to a file that is open only for writing (or reading).
>   If you are doing socket programming, the socket descriptor has got closed before you could do any operation on that and you may end up with this error.

I am using Virtualenv 15.1.0, Python 3.6.0 and Flask 0.12 &

```
$  pip freeze
appdirs==1.4.2
click==6.7
Flask==0.12
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.5
MarkupSafe==0.23
packaging==16.8
pyparsing==2.1.10
requests==2.13.0
six==1.10.0
Werkzeug==0.11.15
```

This is the code I am writing which invokes the error upon exiting the server:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import sqlite3
app = Flask(__name__)

connection = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
connection.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS films (title TEXT, rating INTEGER)')
connection.close()      <------------------ IMPROPER CLOSURE?

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("base.html")

@app.route('/movie', methods = ['POST'])
def add_movie_function():
    connection  = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    cursor      = connection.cursor()
    title       = request.form['title']
    rating      = request.form['rating']
    try:
        query   = 'INSERT INTO films (title, rating) VALUES (?, ?)'
        cursor.execute(query, (title, rating))
        connection.commit()
        message = 'Successfully inserted title and rating data into movies table!'
    except:
        connection.rollback()
        message = 'There was an issue with inserting data into the movies table :('
    finally:
        connection.close() <------------------ IMPROPER CLOSURE?
        return message

@app.route('/movies', methods = ['GET'])
def list_all_movies():
    connection = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM films')
        connection.commit()
        search_result = jsonify(cursor.fetchall())
    except:
        search_result = 'An error occured getting all the film titles'
    finally:
        connection.close() <------------------ IMPROPER CLOSURE?
        return search_result

app.run(debug = True)
```

...and this is the full traceback:

```
(venv) 66 Wed Mar 08 15:29:11$  export FLASK_APP=simpleFlaskAPI.py 
(venv) 67 Wed Mar 08 15:42:08$  flask run
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 230-157-201
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2017 15:42:21] "GET /movies HTTP/1.1" 200 -
^C * Serving Flask app "simpleFlaskAPI"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/python/lesson4/python-minicamp-homework-4/venv/bin/flask", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/username/python/lesson4/python-minicamp-homework-4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 507, in main
    cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
  File "/Users/username/python/lesson4/python-minicamp-homework-4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 374, in main
    return AppGroup.main(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/python/lesson4/python-minicamp-homework-4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/username/python/lesson4/python-minicamp-homework-4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Users/username/python/lesson4/python-minicamp-homework-4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Users/username/python/lesson4/python-minicamp-homework-4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/python/lesson4/python-minicamp-homework-4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args[1:], **kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/python/lesson4/python-minicamp-homework-4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/python/lesson4/python-minicamp-homework-4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 432, in run_command
    use_debugger=debugger, threaded=with_threads)
  File "/Users/username/python/lesson4/python-minicamp-homework-4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 708, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/Users/username/python/lesson4/python-minicamp-homework-4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 670, in inner
    fd=fd)
  File "/Users/username/python/lesson4/python-minicamp-homework-4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 564, in make_server
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd)
  File "/Users/username/python/lesson4/python-minicamp-homework-4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 474, in __init__
    socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 460, in fromfd
    nfd = dup(fd)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

If this is abnormal, should I file a bug report with the folks of Flask?

Thank you!

---

UPDATE per Pipskweak's suggestions, I have modified the script:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)

connection = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
connection.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS films (title TEXT, rating INTEGER)')
connection.close()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("base.html")

@app.route('/movie', methods = ['POST'])
def add_movie_function():
    data = None
    try:
        connection  = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
        with connection:
            cursor      = connection.cursor()
            title       = request.form['title']
            rating      = request.form['rating']
            query   = 'INSERT INTO films (title, rating) VALUES (?, ?)'
            data = cursor.execute(query, (title, rating))
            connection.commit()
            message = 'Successfully inserted title and rating data into movies table!'
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        if connection:
            connection.rollback()
            message = 'There was an issue with inserting data into the movies table :('
        raise ValueError('sqlite3: {}'.format(e))
    finally:
        if connection:
            connection.close()
            print(message)
        if data:
            print(data)
            return message

@app.route('/movies', methods = ['GET'])
def list_all_movies():
    data = None
    try:
        connection = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
        with connection:
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            data = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM films')
            connection.commit()
            search_result = jsonify(cursor.fetchall())
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        if connection:
            search_result = 'An error occured getting all the film titles'
        raise ValueError('sqlite3: {}'.format(e))
    finally:
        if connection:
            connection.close()
            print(search_result)
        if data:
            print(data)
            return search_result

app.run(debug = True)
# if __name__ == '__main__':
#     print('__name__ == "__main__"')
#     app.run(debug = True)
```

OF NOTE: using the `if __name_ == ...` does not invoke debugger mode in Flask when invoking flask by `export FLASK_APP...` and `flask run`. Using `python3 scriptname.py` with the `if name == main`, however, does invoke debugger - so I suspect something is amiss with Flask here?

AND I also adjusted the script to run in python 2 (only a couple print statements and the `except sqlite3.Error, e:` syntax) and tried running it in Flask (using debugger mode) using virtual environment and the python script works fine with the html and when I quit out of the Flask server, no OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor. So, is this a bug I should report to the Flask folks?

FWIW:

```
$  pip freeze  
appdirs==1.4.3  
click==6.7  
Flask==0.12  
itsdangerous==0.24  
Jinja2==2.9.5  
MarkupSafe==1.0  
packaging==16.8  
pyparsing==2.2.0  
requests==2.13.0  
six==1.10.0  
Werkzeug==0.11.15
```

[Perhaps this is a similar issue?](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/830)

Answer (score 1):

So, the `try`, `except`, `finally` statement might be causing some issues.

Did you want to give this a shot? It's a little more specific on the exceptions and closing the connection.

```
def query_db(sql_statement):
    try:
        # connect to database
        conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
        with conn:
            cur = conn.cursor()
            data = cur.execute(sql_statement)
            # commit the changes
            conn.commit()

    except sqlite3.Error, e:
        # if an error has occured, rollback the changes
        if conn:
            conn.rollback()

        # print the error out. Probably useful.
        raise ValueError('sqlite3: {}'.format(e))

    finally:
        # lastly, close the database, probably a good idea.
        if conn:
            conn.close()
        if data:
            return data
```

Also, your missing the `if` statement before `app.run()`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: If sqlite continues to chuck errors, maybe give flask-sqlalchemy a shot, its very pythonic and nice to use, can be a bit tricky, but definitely worth the effort.

Comment: Odd... using `if __name__ == '__main__': app.run(debug = True)` when I run the Flask server it is NOT in debug mode... when I `export FLASK_APP` and `flask run` ? But, if I run the script using `python app.py` it does use debug mode. I am confused... Onward with trying your suggested modification to the try: statement...

Comment: Personally, I have never been of doing the export FLASK_APP, I always just run as `python app.py`, however, that will use python2.7 on Mac, unless the shebang states otherwise

Comment: I've set up virtualenv so that it invokes python3... but I am new to venv as well and more used to invoking python3 explicitly...

Comment: Hmm... `except sqlite3.Error, e:` is throwing a SyntaxError?

Comment: Likely because of python3, I just looked up the docs, try this;

`except sqlite3.Error as e:`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137616/discussion-between-mr-kennedy-and-pipskweak).